# How to choose Radio Button on android studio

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to make a radiobutton, which a radiobutton selected, a edit text is appears.

For example, a have a 2 radio button

```
A. two Edittext appears
B. three edittext appears
```

how i make this?

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ready to 3 EditText

```
    EditText editTextA = null;
    EditText editTextB = null;
    EditText editTextC = null;
```

and when choose A button code:

```
    editTextA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editTextB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editTextC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and when choose B button code:

```
    editTextA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editTextB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editTextC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

when when you choose A button it will just show editTextA,B
and when you choose B, all

Answer (score 0):

use `radioGroup` over `radioButton` and than use setOnCheckedChangeListener for that `radioGroup` and you will get checkedId in listener.

```
.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group,int checkedId){

            Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

            if (checkedId == R.id.a) {
                //some code
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.b) {
                //some code
            }
        }
    });
```